# What is the oldest visual studio version in which monogame's latest version is eligible?

Tags: monogame

I have a low end pc for thelatest versions of visual studio and want to work on monogame so please tell me what version is the last which i should use for the latest monogame version

Comment: Is your PC is too old to run the last version of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/). It's lighter than any Visual Studios. The only downside is that building/deploying to iOS and Android might be difficult. But you can certainly build your games on PC/Linux.

Using VS Code and the `.NET` CLI will require you to know the basics of command-line tools.

Next, You would need to install [.NET Core SDK 5.0](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download).

After the installation is complete, You need to set up Monogame using the following scripts.

```
dotnet new --install MonoGame.Templates.CSharp
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-mgcb-editor
mgcb-editor --register
```

(Taken from [here](https://docs.monogame.net/articles/getting_started/1_setting_up_your_development_environment_ubuntu.html))

Now you're ready to build a project. Open a terminal (CMD or use VS Code) and run

```
dotnet new mgdesktopgl -o MyGame
```

This will create a folder "MyGame" and load a Monogame project. You can run it by heading inside the folder and using

```
dotnet run
```

I wrote an answer on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52107959/6488350) as well.